# Can MySQL automatically specify `_utf8` for inserts to UTF-8 columns?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have a table like this, where one column is latin1, the other is UTF-8:

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `names` (
  `name_english` varchar(255) character NOT NULL,
  `name_chinese` varchar(255) character set utf8 default NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

When I do an insert, I have to type `_utf8` before values being inserted into UTF-8 columns:

```
insert into names (name_english = "hooey", name_chinese = _utf8 "鬼佬");
```

However, since MySQL should know that `name_chinese` is a UTF-8 column, it should be able to know to use `_utf8` automatically.

Is there any way to tell MySQL to use `_utf8` automatically, so when I'm programatically making prepared statements, I don't have to worry about including it with the right parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not to use UTF-8 for the whole table?

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that I still have to specify `_utf8` for every column I insert into.

Comment: No, it does. just issue one query "SET NAMES charset" with every connect. where charset is your site charset @Neil.

Comment: Ah you're right. We can't actually change everything to UTF-8 here just yet, but I wrote a script to automatically put _utf8 in the inserts for the columns that are UTF-8 encoded.